# rxjava : How to pass a set of data down the chain

Tags: group-by, observable, rx-java2

I have a list of records and i want to process 10 records in each iteration. So how can i have an observable that emits a list of 10 records down the chain

The code below is not complete / correct . I have added it to show what i am trying

```
new Function<Cursor, Observable<List<A>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<A>> apply(final Cursor cursor) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<List<A>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<List<A>> e) throws Exception {
                            List <A> list = new ArrayList<Attendee>();

                            Attendee attendee;
                            while ((attendee = pendingUpSyncAttendeeCursor.getNextItem()) != null ) {
                                list.add(pendingUpSyncAttendeeCursor.getNextItem());
                            }

                            e.onNext(list);
                            e.onComplete();

                        }
                    });

                }
            }
    ).groupBy(new Function<List<Attendee>, Object>() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If I understand what you want. Here is a code where form a list of 10 per iteration I return a list of 10 elements of that list

```
@Test
public void twoDeepLevel() {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
    Observable.from(list)
            .flatMap(number -> Observable.from(list)
                    .take(10)
                    .collect(ArrayList<Integer>::new, ArrayList::add))
            .scan(new ArrayList<>(),
                    (lastItemEmitted, newItem) -> {
                        lastItemEmitted.add(newItem);
                        return lastItemEmitted;
                    })
            .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);
}
```

You can see more examples of reactiveX here

https://github.com/politrons/reactive